# How to put one of several queries to separate Y axis in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I have a panel. It shows several queries. It shows them all on one Y axis.

Now how to put one of the queries to another Y axis?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Overrides" window on the right side, create a new field override with the query you want to modify, add the porperty "Axis>Placement" and select the "Right" option.